# Bone Vertex Skinning transformation

Tags: animation, skinning

I am trying to implement skeletal animation in OpenGL.  At this stage, I am trying to have my bone system deform a mesh.  I believe the problem is with how I create the matrix `Bone::getMatrix()`.

**Background:**

Each bone has an offset to it's parent, and if a bone does not have a parent the offset will instead be the world position of the entire skeleton.  A collection of bones comprise a skeleton.  Currently, for testing purposes, I have 3 bones in a skeleton deforming a skinned mesh.

Again, the issue is that when deforming the mesh, the visual result does not produce the desired effect.

**Code:**

```
glm::mat4 Bone::getMatrix(){

    Bone* parent = getParent();
    glm::mat4   rot  = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4   trans= glm::mat4(1.0f);

    glm::vec3 orient = getOrientation();


    //Create Rotation Matrix;
    rot *= glm::rotate(orient.x,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    rot *= glm::rotate(orient.y,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    rot *= glm::rotate(orient.z,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    //Create Translation Matrix
    if(parent  != nullptr){
        glm::vec3 OFF = offset;
        trans = glm::translate(OFF.x,OFF.y,OFF.z);
    }else{
        glm::vec3 pos = getPosition();
        //trans = glm::translate(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z);
    }


    glm::mat4 PM = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    if(parent != nullptr){
        PM *= glm::inverse( parent->getMatrix() );
    }else{
    }
    return PM * trans * rot ;
}
```

Deforming the mesh:

```
void Armature::draw(const float& dt){
    if(mesh == nullptr){
        postMsg("reference copy to mesh is nullptr","draw",34);
        return;
    }

    ArrayVertex3* mesh_Vertex = mesh->getVertex3();
    ArrayVertex3 render_vertex;

    if(mesh_Vertex == nullptr){
        postMsg("mesh vertex structure is null during draw","draw",30);
    }else{
        render_vertex.reserve(mesh_Vertex->size());
    }

    int i=0,j=0,k=0;

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(10,0,0);

        glBegin(GL_POINTS);

        for( i =0; i<this->getBoneCount(); i++){
            glVertex3fv( glm::value_ptr(    glm::vec3(  glm::vec4() * getBone(i)->getMatrix()  )   ));
        }
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);

        for( i =1; i<this->getBoneCount(); i++){

        //  glVertex3fv( glm::value_ptr(getBone(i)->getTranslationMatrix() * glm::mat3(getBone(i)->getRotationMatrix()) ));
        //  glVertex3fv( glm::value_ptr(getBone(i-1)->getTranslationMatrix() * glm::mat3(getBone(i-1)->getRotationMatrix()) ));
        }
        glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

    //Loop all vertices
    for( i = 0 ; i <  int(mesh->getNumberVertexes()); i ++){
        render_vertex[i].vtx = glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f);


        int inf_count = (*mesh_Vertex)[i].numInfluences;

        //Loop all this vertices influences
        for( j=0; j < inf_count; j ++){
            Bone *bone = getBone(    (*mesh_Vertex)[i].boneIDs[j]    );
            float weight = (*mesh_Vertex)[i].boneWeights[j];

            glm::vec4 original_vert = glm::vec4((*mesh_Vertex)[i].vtx,1.0f);
            glm::vec4 original_norm = glm::vec4((*mesh_Vertex)[i].norm,0.0f);


            glm::vec3 T = bone->getTranslationMatrix();

            render_vertex[i].vtx += glm::vec3(  bone->getMatrix()  *  original_vert )   * (weight)  ;


            //Transform normal
            render_vertex[i].norm =  glm::vec3(  bone->getRotationMatrix()  * original_norm )   ;


        }


        (*mesh_Vertex)[i].vtx = render_vertex[i].vtx;
        (*mesh_Vertex)[i].norm = glm::normalize(render_vertex[i].norm);

    }
}
```

Result
[image]

The rotation is not done according to its joint location

Answer (score 2):

I fount your bone matrix function is a bit chaotic. From my understanding, all the vertexes need to be transformed by global transformation matrix. A global transformation matrix is the concatenation of all the local transformation matrix. The following code is used to calculate global transformation. This article is useful.
http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/cse169_w05/2-Skeleton.htm

Some of my previous work using GLSL + assimp + glm
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXBfVl-msYw&list=HL1385555185&feature=mh_lolz

```
glm::mat4 T = glm::translate(bone->offset);
glm::mat4 R = glm::toMat4(bone->rotate); 
glm::mat4 S = glm::scale(bone->scale);
glm::mat4 localTransform = T * R * S; 

if(bone->getID()!=0)
{
    bone->globalTransform = bone->getParent()->globalTransform * localTransform;
}
else
{
    bone->globalTransform = localTransform;
}

for (uint i = 0 ; i < bone->getChildren().size() ; i++) {
    updateTransform(bone->getChildren()[i]);
}
```

Comment: what about inverse bind matrix?

Comment: what is inverse bind matrix? a bit more explanation?

Comment: I think the problem is on glm::inverse(parent->getMatrix()). If the matrix provided by getMatrix() is used to directly manipulate the vertex, the matrix needs to be global matrix. I think you don't need to inverse the parent matrix, just multiple the local matrix on parents global matrix. Or if you want to concatenate the local matrix later (eg. in your draw function), the get matrix function is used to obtain local matrix. The inverse of parent's global matrix can transfer your vertex to local space, but this will conflict with your getMatrix() function which give you a local matrix.